# How to access multiple option values from hash specification

Tags: perl, getopt-long

```
    use Getopt::Long;

    GetOptions(\%gOptions,
        "help",
        "size=i",
        "filename=s{2}",
    );
```

I am passing options like -

```
--size 200 --filename abc.txt def.txt
```

I tried accessing filename from the hash specification through

```
my @array = $gOptions{filename};
print $array[0];
print $array[1];
```

However, this is not working. How to access multiple option values from a hash specification `%gOptions`?

Note :
I can map `filename` to separate array like this -

```
"filename=s{2}" => \@filearray,
print "$filearray[1];"
```

but I am not preferring this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash) on this form of usage says:

> For options that take list or hash values, it is necessary to indicate this by appending an @ or % sign after the type

and it will then use a reference to an array or hash in the appropriate field to hold values.

So...

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Getopt::Long;

my %gOptions;

GetOptions(\%gOptions,
  "help",
  "size=i",
  # The @ has to come after the type, and before the repeat count.
  # Note the single quotes so @{2} isn't subject to variable interpolation
  'filename=s@{2}', 
);

say for $gOptions{"filename"}->@* if exists $gOptions{"filename"};
# or @{$gOptions{"filename"}} if your perl is too old for postderef syntax
```

Example:

```bash
$ perl foo.pl --filename a b
a
b
```

Comment: Instead of $gOptions{"filename"}->@* can you suggest a simpler option to just print 0th index of this array ?

Comment: @CoolCamel See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) for a start if you don't know how to work with arrayrefs (In particular, **Use Rule 2**). Considering how vital references are to any but the most trivial of data structures in perl, you'll need to get comfortable with them.

Comment: I tried using $gOptions{"filename"}->[0] but it is not working

Comment: That's the correct syntax and would be "a" in my example. What does *not working* mean?

Comment: i am getting an error that using uninitialized value of  $gOptions{"filename"}->[0]  which means it is not able to parse it correctly in this way.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I used double quotes for filename=s@{2} and forgot to give \ before @

Comment: Ah, yeah. Needs single quotes or an escape to avoid interpolation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249808/discussion-between-cool-camel-and-shawn).

Comment: Thanks Shawn for helping, finding the right reference is the most difficult part ! :)